# Rails app passenger nginx index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

When i open my rails app on server i get an nginx error, in the log it says:

> /home/deploy/kingdoms/current/public/index.html" is not found (2: No
>   such file or directory)

I think it has something to do with

passenger.conf

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;

passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

nxing conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##



    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Phusion Passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: do you have a site config for your app?

Comment: paste your nginx configuration.

Comment: I have added my nginx config

Comment: Do you have your site-enabled?

Comment: @StephenC yes in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default i have
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        server_name kingdoms.chrisvandermeer.nl;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /home/deploy/kingdoms/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, the guide on gorails had the wrong public path in the sites enabled config

Comment: Just ran into the same error following their tutorial...

Comment: I seem to fall into the same problem, but still cannot figure out the solution. Can you please share where exactly was the problem with the public path?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yourApp`

look for the line that starts with `root` and set the directory to the location of your app. e.g

root `/var/www/yourApp/current/public`

then restart nginx `sudo service nginx restart`

That will solve it